# confusion by java versions in my MacOs(Catalina)

Tags: java, homebrew

Recently, I want to upgrade my java from 8 to 11. Then checking my machine using `java -version`, it shows as follows:

```
java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)
```

Then, I think there is only java-8 there. But then I use `homebrew` with `brew install java11` it shows this:

```
==> Formulae
app-engine-java             java                        javacc     jslint4java                 pdftk-java
google-java-format          java11 ✔                    javarepl   libreadline-java
==> Casks
eclipse-java                        eclipse-javascript                  oracle-jdk-javadoc                  homebrew/cask-versions/java-beta

If you meant "java" specifically:
It was migrated from homebrew/cask to homebrew/core.
```

I am confused now: are these 2 versions installed in my machine, or only one there? If 2 here, how to I specify the path if I want to use java11.

Answer (score 0):

In Homebrew, `java11` is an alias for the formula `openjdk@11`. What you want is a cask, specifically `temurin11`, which can be installed by running this command:

```
brew install homebrew/cask-versions/temurin11
```

(Temurin is the official successor of AdoptOpenJDK.)